# Get Image from the Storage Folder in View - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to show the default.jpg avatar picture in my Laravel 5.4 `profile.blade.php`.

- I created a link between the public folder and the storage folder with: `php artisan storage:link`.
- The file is stored:

[image]

- I check in the source code of my webpage which showed the `src="/public/storage/uploads/avatar/default.jpg"`

But still no image could be found. Could someone explain to me what I am missing?

Comment: i think you are missing  `/public/storage/app/uploads/avatar/default.jpg`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove `public` from path and image will be shown if you set correct link

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I will accept you're answer when I am allowed to

Answer (score 4):

You can use this in the view once the storage link is present:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/avatar/default.jpg') }}" alt="" />
```

That will generate the full asset url to your image.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
     <img src="{{ asset('/storage/app/uploads/avatar/default.jpg') }}">
```

And, Your `/storage/...../default.jpg` should be inside laravel public folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can get file from storage folder directly so you need to create symbolic link between a folder in your storage directory and public directory.

```
ln -s path/to/public/storage/uploads/avatar/ /path/to/laravel/public/avatar
```

Then you will able to get it directly in blade :

```
<img src="{{ asset('/avatar/default.jpg') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

remove public from the path  `src="/public/storage/uploads/avatar/default.jpg"`